# how to remove index from array and make it plain in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

Referring to the picture, how do I make the first array with indexes `0,1,2` to become like second array without index?

[image]

The first array is created by using the `array.push` method;

```
var between = [];
```

and within loop

```
between.push(newdate.getFullYear() + '-' + (newdate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +  newdate.getDate());
```

I Googled, but all answers I'm getting is on how to remove array item by index.

EDIT:

```js
var between = [];
var array = ["2017-11-20", "2017-11-21", "2017-11-22"];

for (var i = 0; i < 3 i++) {
  between.push(newdate.getFullYear() + '-' + (newdate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + newdate.getDate());
}

console.log(between[0]); //undefined
console.log(array[0]); //2017-11-20
```

Comment: that's just the browser console behavior..... both are the same.... one is shown when you are opened console..... another one when it's in a hidden state...

Comment: How do you want to delete actually like by index or by value

Comment: @AshiqEmran, i dont want to delete any value form the array, but I want to convert teh first one like the second one

Comment: All arrays have indexes. You seem confused by how the console is displaying the information. There is no difference in the structure of your two arrays.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, why then I can't access this  console.log(between[0]); for first array but second array can?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your exact code. I'd suggest you edit the question to give a more complete example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, added below EDIT: in my post can see the code there?

Comment: Thanks for editing, although it doesn't really help as your code doesn't define `data` or `newdate`

Answer (score 0):

**You missed your semicolon nothing else**

```
var between = [];
var array = ["2017-11-20", "2017-11-21", "2017-11-22"];

for (var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
  between.push(newdate.getFullYear() + '-' + (newdate.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + newdate.getDate());
}

console.log(between[0]); //undefined
console.log(array[0]); //2017-11-20
```

Comment: i dont want to delete

Comment: what you exactly want to do

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question

Comment: kindly careful when you are asking question